# Read a text file in python line wise

Tags: python, file

I have created the following text file :

```
fo = open("foo.txt", "wb")
fo.write("begin \n")
fo.write("end \n")
fo.write("if \n")
fo.write("then \n")
fo.write("else \n")
fo.write("identifier \n")


input = raw_input("Enter the expression : ")
print input
fo = open("foo.txt" , "rt")
str = fo.read(10)
print "Read string is : ", str
fo.close()
```

What should i be doing to read the text file line-wise?? I tried fo.read() and fo.readlines() but i am not getting the expected output!!!

Comment: And what is your output?

Comment: Have a look at this section of the Tutorial in the Python docs - [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: i got what i was looking for using linecache.getline('Filename.txt', Line_number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working but you didn't use it in the right way:

```
for line in fo.readlines():
    print line
```

Comment: Or even ```for line in fo:```

Comment: i got what i was looking for using linecache.getline('Filename.txt', Line_number)

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the file for writing, but not closing it before trying to read from it.
You need to add a `fo.close()` before the `fo.read`

also, `read(10)` reads 10 bytes of data from the file, and `wb` means your'e writing binary data. I'm not so sure thats what you want...

Comment: Not to mention shadowing `input` and `str`... But none of these mistakes actually prevent the program from doing what it's been told to do. :)

Comment: what should i do to store 1st line in one variable, the 2nd line in another variable and so on...

Comment: @WeaselFox : writing the fo.close() before fo.read() wont actually work.

Comment: i got what i was looking for using linecache.getline('Filename.txt', Line_number)

Comment: Every line contains a single string. How can i store each string in a different varibale?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you're opening the file in the wrong mode (binary, instead of text, notice the open arguments below). You need to use the readlines method to iterate over the lines of the file.

```
#Using a context manager to open the file in write text mode
with open("foo.txt", "w") as fo:
    fo.write("begin \n")
    #write other lines...
    ...

input = raw_input("Enter the expression : ")
print input
#Open in read text mode
with open("foo.txt" , "r") as fi:
    for line in fi.readlines():
        print "Read string is : ", str
```

Comment: Every line contains a single string. How can i store each string in a different varibale?